# Converting JPA specification to JPQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jpa-criteria

we have JPA Specifications defined on an entity. I want to convert that specification to JPQL So I can create join it with some other entity. (I tried using parent-child relationship but that's not efficient, and that doesn't allow us to put filtering(specifications) on chile entity). Earlier We were reading from a single table so we had specifications in place that was working fine. Now we need to join this with another entity, For that I want to use JPQL over specifications. I want to convert specification on one table to JPQL and than join it with other entity.

Answer (score 0):

Use @query annotation on your repository method and write your JPQL query inside the @query annotation.

you can refer table names with your entity name inside the @query annotation.

Comment: Nope, I want to convert existing specifications to JPQL, Like: String jpql = query.where(....);

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have User and List  entities

In JPQL you will write something like this

```
public List<User> getUserByName(String username) {
    String queryString = "select u from User u where u.name= '"+username+"' ";
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

**With JPA and Hibernate older than 5.1**

even with JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.0 it’s still not possible to join two unrelated entities.

If User and UserAddress are not related to each other

```
List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u, UserAddress ua WHERE u.firstName = ua.firstName AND u.lastName = ua.lastName").getResultList();
```

Hibernate will transform this as cross join something like this

```
User user01_ cross join UserAddress useraddress1_
```

**With Hibernate 5.1**

Same quesry will be treated as inner Join

```
List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u, UserAddress ua WHERE u.firstName = ua.firstName AND u.lastName = ua.lastName").getResultList();

User user01_ inner Join UserAddress useraddress1_
```

**Other Imp Point:**

Using subqueries in the join clause is not allowed. in JPQL, subqueries are only allowed in the WHERE and HAVING part.

Comment: My question is to convert Specification to Query, Is there any way we can do that? Without rewriting Specification to JPQL.